# Kendo Tree View show number of checked children

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to achieve the following with my Kendo Tree View. I want to show the number of checked children after the name of the parent (i.e. in the example below 15 out of 18 children are checked).

[image: Kendo Tree View number of items checked]

I was hoping to achieve this using the template function but unfortunately I can't access the checked value of the children.

```
template: (row: any) => {
    rowTemplate = `<span>${row.item.label}</span>`;
    // The result below is always an empty array
    // The template may be getting fired before the data source has initialised. 
    console.log(row.item.children.view());
    return rowTemplate;
 }
```

In the above code, the call to get the children is always an empty array. I was hoping to count the checked children and use that in my template.

Is there a way I can access the values of the children within the template function?

There may be a better way to achieve this. I may also face issues trying to get the template to rebind each time a checkbox is updated. For reference, I am using AngularJS.